# Programming pic mcu using serial connector, without using pickit

Tags: microcontroller, pic, bootloader, serial-communication

How do I dump bootloader (.hex) file to my pic18f4620 mcu using usb to serial connector(RS232)? I am not using pickit like burner/ programmer device. And as well how do I enable/ disable in-circuit programming mode?

Comment: I think this question belongs to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks was not knowing whether there was separate site started. Is there a way to transfer the question to electronic stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

In all cases that I know of you need to manipulate PIC pins MCLR, DATA, CLK & PGM to program a blank processor.  It is possible to use a parallel port and minimal hardware to do this.  Using a serial port controlled by a USB connection will be so much more difficult to implement than the parallel port approach it is unlikely any such solutions will be found.